# segfault in g_slice_alloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glib, gstring

I am calling a function with the following lines:

```
void call_system_command(const char *command_params)
{
    GString *cmd = g_string_sized_new(1024);
    g_string_append_printf(cmd, "/bin/bash /path/to/my/script '%s'", command_params);
    system(cmd->str);
    g_string_free(cmd, TRUE);
}
```

I am getting segfault in the line with g_string_sized_new.
Backtrace from gdb shows:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000320ce56264 in g_slice_alloc () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x000000320ce5c3db in g_string_sized_new () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
....
```

I have tried exporting G_SLICE=always-malloc, so that instead of glib's own allocator, malloc is used. However the problem remains same.
I am still getting segfault in g_slice_alloc.
Also I am calling this function 'call_system_command' from multiple threads.
Could that be a problem?

The function is a part of plugin that is called by cron every 15 minutes. The segfault does not occur every time the plugin is executed but one every 3-4 days.

Any pointers on further debugging will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us a minimal, compilable testcase. "Minimal" means "using only the bare essentials required to reproduce this problem", and "compilable" means "able to compile and debug on our systems without filling in the blanks or fixing basic syntax errors".

Answer (score 0):

You should run your application under Valgrind to help chase this, it sounds like heap corruption.

You mention threads, which of course is good information since it can make it easier to end up in trouble.

The glib documentation states:

> GLib itself is internally completely thread-safe (all global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons.

And since the slice API doesn't expose any data structure instances, it should be safe to call from multiple threads.

Comment: Running the plugin in valgrind makes it too slow. It will take hours to complete. I tried running the function in valgrind though a test program but could not reproduce the segfault.

Comment: ... and what did valgrind tell you? Did it mention any problems? If not, then you've misdiagnosed, and you need to broaden your horizon because the error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Wrote the following  test program to identify the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#pragma GCC optimize("O0")

#define NUM 20
void* run(void *d)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        GString *str = g_string_sized_new(1024);
        g_string_append_printf(str, "%s", "hello hello\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", str->str);
        g_string_free(str, TRUE);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < NUM; j++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, run, (void*) NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The following segfault occurs consistently

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffecdfa700 (LWP 11277)]
0x000000320ce56257 in g_slice_alloc () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glib2-2.22.5-6.el6.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `pthread_join` statement? Your main function actually could finish before your threaded functions return - that could destroy the thread objects themselfes. As far as I know `pthread_exit` is supposed to be used *only* within the spawned threads, and not within the mainthread (http://cs.gmu.edu/~white/CS571/Examples/pthread_examples.html, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html)
So your demo is (possibly) not optimal, and may incorporate the same issue cause as your program.

Did you try to just manually `malloc` a same sized bunch of memory and check again with valgrind and gdb.